# Parse object to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have some web services that receive JSON data send by jquery method.
But I need to edit the object before send this data. Is there any way to parse a JSON object to a simple object in javascript, modify it and then parse it again to JSON. or maybe update this JSON object without parse it?

Comment: I realized that is a string, I had to use JSON.Parse to get the JSON object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To go from a JSON string to a JavaScript object: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), or [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) if you're using jQuery and concerned about compatibility with older browsers.

To go from a JavaScript object to a JSON string: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

---

> If I've already do this var myData = JSON.stringify({ oJson:{data1 :1}}); and then I want to update that information setting data1 = 2, what is the best way to do this?

```
var myData = JSON.stringify({ oJson:{data1 :1}});
// later...
parsedData = JSON.parse(myData);
parsedData.oJson.data1 = 2;
myData = JSON.stringify(parsedData);
```

Even better though, if you save a reference to the object before stringifying it, you don't have to parse the JSON at all:

```
var obj = { oJson:{data1 :1}};
var myData = JSON.stringify(obj);
// later...
obj.oJson.data1 = 2;
myData = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: If I've already do this var myData = JSON.stringify({ oJson:{data1 :1}}); and then I want to update that information setting data1 = 2, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: @Juan: Why don't you manipulate the data *before* stringify it? All you need to know is in the answer anyway. What more do you need?

Comment: How about just setting `data1` to `2` before stringifying it?

Comment: Because the last value depends on an ajax response during the execution of a process

Answer (score 3):

```
var parsed = JSON.parse('{"a": 1}');
parsed.b = 2;
var string = JSON.stringify(parsed);
//string is: '{"a":1,"b":2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following should work...

```
//Convert your JSON object into a JavaScript object
var myObject = JSON.parse(json);

//You can then manipulate the JavaScript object like any other
myObject.SomeValue = "new";

//Then you can convert back to a JSON formatted string
json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

As JSON is an JavaScript object you can simply manipulate it with JavaScript.

Comment: No, JSON is a data exchange format and only exist as *string* in JavaScript. But true, JavaScript provides string methods as well.

Comment: But also a JavaScript object in the context of JavaScript, maybe you mean a JSON string.

Comment: Maybe you refer to object literals as JSON as well, but that does not make it correct. JSON is the official name of the data-interchange format, so if you talk about JSON I have to assume you are talking about this format. In fact, the only point where the specification talks about JSON is when [it describes the `JSON` object with its `parse` and `stringify` methods](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.12). Otherwise, object literals are also called *object initializers*.

Comment: And he's rigth that a simple eval() can be used to parse any valid JSON object, however it's discouraged as it contains security holes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get a javascript object:

```
var jsObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then you could modify `jsObject` and turn it back into a JSON string with `JSON.stringify`.

This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) has more information on it.